# suppress or "auto-confirm" dialog box opened by OLE server

Tags: winapi, windows-server-2003, ole

I have an app which instantiates a local OLE server.

Under certain conditions this server opens a dialog box in response to a call to one of it's exposed methods.

Do by any means there is a possibility to suppress this box, or somehow "auto-confirm" it?

The issue is the app shall run as scheduled task, and hangs if the dialog pops up.

I have access to the app's sources, but not to the OLE server's sources.

This is on win2k3.

Comment: You'll need to ask the authors of the component that shows the dialog. Only they will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by a somehow more or less reliable workaround, depending on the uniqueness of the pop-up window's text caption.

I wrote a small program, which scans all top-level windows using `EnumWindows()`, graps their caption using `GetWindowText()`, compares the caption to a pattern provided on program startup and if a match occurs posts (using `PostMesssage()`) a `WM_CLOSE` to this window.

This process is repeated every T milli-seconds.

This programm is run in parallel to the process creating the OLE server which opens the unwanted pop ups and closes them latest after T milli-seconds.

If run every 1000ms seconds no visible system load appears.

Using VC10 the binary is very light weighted (<8k), the only dependency is `msvcr100.dll`, no setup is needed, if the latter is put in the same directory as the binary itself. I built it on win7 and it runs seamlessly under win2k and win2k3 ... :-)

The sources to this solution (along with VC10 solution/project files) can be found here: https://github.com/ealk/wd